# Heroku Recover App configured on winodows in ubuntu platform

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I created and worked on Ruby on Rails shopify App deployed On Heroku few months ago. I didn't push any code to github. Now i have to work on the same app on different system. I dont have access to my previous system. How can i get my app files. Is there any way to get the code from heroku as i didn't push code to github. How can i configure my current system to access my heroku account and push modified code to the app. I previously worked on Windows. Now i am currently working on Ubuntu Platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can get the source code from Heroku by `git clone` command.

```
  $   heroku git:clone -a app_name
```

replace `app_name` with your app's name. For **[more details](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app)**

---

For **GitHub** : If you want to get source code from github. In terminal go to appropriate directory where you want to save app folder then run this below code.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/user_name/yourapp.git
```

github's clone address you can get from

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was able to fetch code using this command.
Now i want to modify this code. Do i only need to add new ssh keys to heroku account and start pushing code. Is there anything else i need to do.

Comment: @user3159596 : Do you have your app on heroku already or want to deploy? If it is there already then you just need to `git push heroku master`  you can also check [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git) for more help. It also described if you want it from scratch...